# check if all element of a column of a pandas dataframe are equal to a particular value

Tags: python, pandas

Hello given a dataframe I would like to check that all the values of a particular column are equal to 9.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[2,9],[np.nan,9],[3,9]],columns=['A','B'])

df
        A   B
    0   1.0 2
    1   2.0 9
    2   NaN 9
    3   3.0 9
```

My solution would be:

```
if ((df.loc[:,"B"].unique()==[9]).all()):
     ...
```

Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
if df.B.eq(9).all():
    print ('all values are 9')
```

EDIT: Like mentioned @mozway use:

```
assert df.B.eq(9).all()
#AssertionError
```

With custom error:

```
if df.B.ne(9).any():
    raise Exception('All values in column are not equal 9')
    
Exception: All values in column are not equal 9
```

Comment: if I want to raise an error if all the elements are not equal to 9 I just ~df.B.eq(9).all() ?

Comment: Use `assert df.B.eq(9).all()`

Comment: @gabboshow - Do you need some specific error? Or `AssertionError` ?

Comment: raise Execption.... what about df.B.ne(9).any()

Comment: @gabboshow - added to answer.